# Beginner Python math road-block

Tags: python

Problem: When driving on a trip I often notice indicating the number of miles to some city or town and wonder how long before I will get there. Produce code that will accept my speed and the distance I need to travel and indicate how long (in minutes) it will take me to get there. (Remember that MPH tells how many miles I can travel in 60 minutes.)

Here is the code I have produced so far. I believe the issue is in line 5 or 6 but I'm stumped. I'm able to enter in my MPH (70) and my distance (120). My answer should be 102.857..... but it won't compute.

```
answer1 = input("Please enter the speed you will be traveling in MPH: ")
mph = int(answer1)
answer2 = input("Please enter the distance you will be traveling: ")
distance = int(answer2)
time = float((answer2 / answer1) * answer1)
print("That will take " +str(time) + " minutes.")
```

Comment: Instead of concatenation, use interpolation: `print(f'That will take {time} minutes.')` on Python >=3.6 or format strings on <3.6: `print("That will take {} minutes.".format(time))`

Comment: Is this Python 3? If not, you need `raw_input()`.

Comment: Also please explain what you mean by "won't compute".

Comment: you're line 5 is using the input values, not the integer values from mph and distance.

Comment: So, when you divide - you're trying to divide a string and not an integer.

Comment: Show your stack trace

Answer (score 2):

There were some problems with your code, namely trying to divide a string and an integer and using the wrong formula for the time calculation. Here's the code with the issues fixed.

```
answer1 = input("Please enter the speed you will be traveling in MPH: ")
mph = float(answer1)
answer2 = input("Please enter the distance you will be traveling: ")
distance = float(answer2)
time = float((distance / mph) * 60)
print("That will take " +str(time) + " minutes.")
```

Output:

```
Please enter the speed you will be traveling in MPH: 70
Please enter the distance you will be traveling: 120
That will take 102.85714285714285 minutes.
```

Answer (score 0):

when you read an input from the terminal it is read in as a string. You are converting the `answer1` and `answer2` to int and storing them in `mph` and `distance` respectively but use the original strings for computation. Use the following code for the 5th line.

```
time = float((distance / mph) * mph)
```

Comment: This will solve the error - but note that the time formula is still wrong.

Comment: Also, no need to use `float` in py 3. If you do use it, apply to each argument before doing division in py2, or integer truncation will occur before the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It is python problem. When you divide with int. it may give you wrong result. Please make sure that your every input is float type. it will help you to get your desired answer.